# Need help proving this conjecture on subarrays

Tags: algorithms

**Conjecture:**

Given an array N (containing both positive and negative integers) all of its subarray K to have the same sum, the sub arrays need to have the same elements in the same order as the first Kth subarray, **when N is an integer multiple of K.**

---

For example:

```
N = 9
K = 3
Array = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

The above array satisfies the conjecture but I am unable to proof the conjecture or create a contradictory example.

**How can we be absolutely certain the conjecture will hold ?**

Any type of intuitive explanation?

Related to this [coding question on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71814244/7134737)

Thanks

Comment: Not sure your question is clear,  but if $n_1+n_2+\cdots +n_k=n_2+\cdots+n_k+n_{k+1}$ then $n_1=n_{k+1}$.  Similarly, $n_2=n_{k+2}$ and, more generally, $n_i=n_{k+i}$.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @lulu Yes it does. You might want to put it in the answer.